# Python3: print specific values from json

Tags: python-3.6

Python 3: 
I need to print the name, email, city, phone for all users in a json file.
I am just learning Python, so I don't know what code to use.

I can get the file, but don't know what to do to print the correct info.

```
#Imported functions
import requests
import json

#Using the following API endpoint: 
#https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

#Use the GET method of the requests library to read and JSON encode your request.
r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
data = r.json()
print(r)
print()
print(data)
```

I want a nicely formatted list of the name, email, city, phone for all users.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, you must try to research and code, and post with a specific problem, this website is not for complete homework resolution. Split your problem is little parts and try to solve each one.

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
data = r.json()

for row in data:
    print("Name: {}\nEmail: {}\nCity: {}\nPhone: {}\n".format(row['name'], row['email'],row['address']['city'],row['phone']))
    # alternative to the line above
    # print("Name: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nCity: {address[city]}\nPhone: {phone}\n".format_map(row))
```

Short explanation: `data` contains a list of the entries in the json-file that you are requesting. In this case 10 entries -> so data will have 10 items.

```
for row in data:
    print(...)
```

will loop through `data` (the list with 10 entries) and each entry will be written to `row`. each row will be printed out, in a certain format. not the whole row, but certain fields in that row. you access them by their key. in this case`['name']` and so on...

Comment: yeah, but since @Neal is a beginner, it is good to know how to access certain items in a dict, by using keys. i updated the code though

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks! How do I now take this data I printed and put it in a CSV file?